# Unable to use the insert method in google app engine endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-asynctask, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm building an android app that access a server. I'm using a full google solution. The backend is in GAE and I'm using endpoints to expose my API, I'm also using GCM. I use the auto generate tools that are offered by android studio to get my classes.

In my app module I have a class called offer, this is where I put data to be sent to the server, I have also an AsyncTask class that allows to make the api call.

In my backend module I have the exposed API and I also I have a class offer from which the API is generated by android studio and app engine sdk.

Now my problem is I made an attempt, but it resulted in failure, its like the classes in app and backend are not compatible. Whereas they are the same, in fact the one in backend is a simple copy from the one in app, the difference is the "objectify" annotation that I added. Below are pieces from my code and screenshots of my project structure.

```
    public class InsertOfferAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Offer, Void, Boolean>{

    private static OfferApi offer_service;
    private Context context;

    public InsertOfferAsyncTask(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Offer... offer) {

      if (offer_service == null) {

        OfferApi.Builder builder = new OfferApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setRootUrl("https://flawless-snow-95011.appspot.com/_ah/api/");


        offer_service = builder.build();
    }


    try {
        offer_service.insert(offer[0]); //this where I make the actual API call, I know I shouldn't use Object, it was an attempt to make it work
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return true;
    }
```

This is a part from where I call the AsyncTask, which is the code above.

```
     Log.i("offer", offer.getUsr_id());
            Log.i("offer_id", String.valueOf(offer.getId()));
            Log.i("offer_date", offer.getPost());
            new         InsertOfferAsyncTask(getActivity().getBaseContext()).execute(offer);
            getActivity().finish();
```

All the code above is taken from my app module, the following is the endpoint code that code generated, I am posting only the part I make a call to.

```
    @ApiMethod(
        name = "insert",
        path = "offer",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
public Offer insert(Offer offer) {

    ofy().save().entity(offer).now();
    logger.info("Created Offer with ID: " + offer.getId());

    return ofy().load().entity(offer).now();
}
```

[image: Screenshot of my project tree]

What I need now is how I can use what I have to send my data to the server. I know that I can connect to the server, I tested.

This is the error message, that i get when I try to build.

```
    Error:(233, 73) error: no suitable method found for execute(.model.Offer) 
    method AsyncTask.execute(Runnable) is not applicable
    (actual argument .model.Offer cannot be converted to Runnable by method invocation conversion)
    method AsyncTask.execute(backend.model.offerApi.model.Offer...) is not applicable
    (argument type app.model.Offer does not conform to vararg element type backend.model.offerApi.model.Offer)
```

Any help?? should I use JSON (I doubt, the job is done by the auto-generated classes, as it is shown in the builder)

Comment: Is the client (app) `Offer` class one provided by the auto-generated Endpoints Android [client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients)?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are using two different "Offer" objects
`app.model.Offer` and `backend.model.offerApi.model.Offer`?

The type `backend.model.offerApi.model.Offer` appears to be the one generated for your Endpoints API, you need to use that type everywhere on the client (android) side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of this, however, in general I don't have access to the object, if it was iOS or JavaScript, I couldn't have access to it, how would I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should create a separate project that contains all classes that are shared between the android app and your api.